# Is there a way to update a particular object in Array Controller in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, controller, nsarraycontroller

In objective-c i would do like this to update a value of an object in an Array Controller.

[[[moviesListAC selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0] setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"movieName"] forKey:@"movieName"];

Where moviesListAC is my NSArrayController

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSArrayController *moviesListAC;

Note : This Swift code didn't work :

moviesListAC.selectedObjects()[0]["movieName"] = (dict["movieName"] as? String)

Comment: Is 'didn't work' doesn't change or isn't displayed? Does the Objective-C code work?

Comment: Ocj-c code works in fine obj-c project. But in swift project i see compile time error : moviesListAC.selectedObjects()[0]["movieName"] = (dict["movieName"] as? String)

Comment: i am using a work around like this - moviesListAC.insert(...) & moviesListAC.remove(...) which is not the right way. Anybody know the correct way to do that?

Comment: What is the compile time error?

Comment: When i use this code : 

self.mainArrayController.selectedObjects()[0]["movieName"] = "Hello"

i get this error message :

Cannot call value of non-fucntion type '[Any]!'

When i use this code : 

self.mainArrayController.selectedObjects[0]["movieName"] = "Hello"

i get this error message :

Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift but I think you have to tell Swift that `selectedObjects` is an array of `Dictionary` or that `selectedObjects[0]` is a `Dictionary`.

Comment: I tied that :
(moviesListAC.selectedObjects[0] as! [String:Any]).updateValue("New Movie" as! Any, forKey: "movieTitle") 

any i get this error : Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type '[String : Any]'

My question is simple : Is there a way to update an object of an Array Controller in Swift?

Comment: `(moviesListAC.selectedObjects[0] as! NSMutableDictionary)["movieName"] = (dict["movieName"] as? String)`.

Comment: I get this error now.....
Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NativeDictionaryStorageOwner<Swift.String, Any>' (0x10134a860) to 'NSMutableDictionary' (0x7fffea3fa1b0).
2017-03-07 15:04:44.479545 MoviePal[3191:86645] Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NativeDictionaryStorageOwner<Swift.String, Any>' (0x10134a860) to 'NSMutableDictionary' (0x7fffea3fa1b0).

Comment: What is `objectClass` ("Class Name" in IB) of the array controller?

Comment: NSArrayController

Comment: I mean "Class Name" in the Attributes Inspector, above "Prepares Content". It is the object class to use when creating new objects. And what is the class of the elements of the content array of the array controller?

Comment: NSMutableDictionary

Comment: The problem is selectedObjects is Read-Only in Swift.  open var selectedObjects: [Any]! { get }

Comment: That isn't a problem, you don't modify `selectedObjects`. The content of your arraycontroller contains immutable Swift `Dictionary`s.

Comment: oh ok. Then how do i resolve the issue? My Original Question was ... Is there a way to update an object of an Array Controller in Swift?

Comment: The object must be updatable = mutable.

Comment: Yes i know that. How do i make it updatable? Is there a way? If yes can you please help me How with code sample?

Comment: I don't know about mutable Swift Dictionaries but `NSMutableDictionary` is mutable. Another option is a custom class but I don't know if Swift and bindings will work.